# Starting ArcMap Python Add-in as service?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, python-addin

Is it possible to start Python add-in as a service which keeps running while in ArcMap?

I am designing something using a add-in to receive socket messages from out of ArcMap and do some operations based on this message.

Comment: You can start an addin at startup, that's no problem, the trouble with this is that Esri ArcMap is a single thread process so you've got to watch what you do on a background worker or other thread.. if you are careless you **will** crash ArcMap. What do you need to do with your socket messages? What language are you working in?

Comment: It's actually a license terms violation to run Desktop as a server.  ArcGIS Server exists to fulfill the server role (and it's pretty good at it).

Comment: I'm not sure that is what the OP means @Vince, I think it's more like a resident thread that responds to specific events raised by ArcMap and does something, for example sending an email when a specific feature is edited or opening a document when a feature is selected.. that sort of thing. Trying to create an addin for ArcGis to serve web pages would be so much work that the user may as well start with MapServer and modify/customize from there.

Comment: @MichaelStimson I am looking forward to send a geojson to ArcMap so that ArcMap can zoom the current workspace to the area. I am working with python

Comment: ArcMap doesn't do GeoJSON, you will need an intermediary process to convert to something Esri *does* like, a shapefile would be good. I would suggest OGR which is part of the GDAL package to convert the JSON file to a shapefile then load the shapefile into ArcMap. Caveat: OGR isn't the only package that will perform a conversion, GDAL/OGR is the only one that I know.

Comment: @MichaelStimson yes I realized I can pass the extent to arcmap and let it do the zoom. I already made a button to do so. The hard part is that how to keep the addin live so that the user doesn’t have to click the button every time

Comment: What is it that the addin does? All I know so far is that it zooms to the extent of a GeoJSON file.. what is it the addin will do whilst *live*? If you're not needing to change the current tool you can implement an addin as ITool which will remain active whilst still the *current tool*. You could also assign a keyboard shortcut to your tool or functions in your tool.

Comment: @MichaelStimson okay let me explain it in detail. We have a web application which can send messages through socket. The message will includes an extent of data frame work. I want the python add in receive this message and zoom current data frame to the specified extent. Ideally, the addin should keep running when user start it. Then whenever add in’s socket receives a message, it should run the zoom function with the extent contained in the message. Is it clear? Thank you so much Michael

Comment: If you're activating a current tool and not deactivating it by selecting any other tool it will stay resident. You need to create your addin as a tool http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/python-addins/creating-an-add-in-tool.htm

Comment: @MichaelStimson Thanks! I will try this and post the result here.